# How am i able to Display every try another Password (tkinter Entry Field)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I created a Tool which allows me to display a Password in a Tkinter Entryfield.

The Goal is: to get every Button click a another Password displayed.

The Problem is (i think) that i dont clear the Variable at some point and execute the Code which creates the Password again to display a new Password. With this Script i only get the same Password displayed

How should i do it?

```
import customtkinter
from tkinter import *
import secrets
import string

class EasyPass(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Form/GUI
        self.title("EasyPass")
        self.geometry(f"{300}x{100}")
        self.resizable(False,False)

        # GuiWidgets
        self.label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self,
                                       text="EasyPass v1"   ,
                                       width=120,
                                       height=25,
                                       corner_radius=8)
        self.label.place(relx=0.30, rely=0.045,)

        self.pass_creator_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self,
                                         width=100,
                                         height=50,
                                         border_width=0,
                                         corner_radius=8,
                                         text="Password Creator",
                                         command=self.pass_creator)
        self.pass_creator_button.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.3)

        self.pass_checker_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self,
                                                           width=100,
                                                           height=50,
                                                           border_width=0,
                                                           corner_radius=8,
                                                           fg_color= "grey",
                                                           text="Password Checker",
                                                           command=self.pass_check)
        self.pass_checker_button.place(relx=0.557, rely=0.3)



    def pass_creator(self):
        def fill_password(password):
            passEntry.delete(0, END)
            passEntry.insert(0, password)


        alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "@$!%*?&'/"
        password = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(10))

        window = customtkinter.CTkToplevel(self)
        window.geometry("300x150")
        window.title("Password Creator")

        # create label on CTkToplevel window
        label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(window, text="Create your Password")
        label.place(relx=0.28, rely=0.03)

        #create Entry Field to display created password
        passEntry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(window, placeholder_text="",
                                                justify='center', text_color="#DDE6E8", width=200,
                                                text_font=("Segoe UI", 15, "bold"))
        passEntry.pack( padx=5, pady=30)

        # Button to create the password
        pass_creator_button1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(window,
                                                     width=100,
                                                     height=50,
                                                     border_width=0,
                                                     corner_radius=8,
                                                     text="Create Password",
                                                     command=lambda: fill_password(f"{password}"))
        pass_creator_button1.place(relx=0.30, rely=0.5)


    def pass_check(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = EasyPass()
    app.mainloop()
```

Thanks for every help

Comment: Try moving password generation to `def fill_password`. And don't pass any arguments to this function. Clear entry, create password, insert.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i fixxed it by deleting the param in fill_password, and the formatted string in the lambda func